# Replace CHAR with VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, replace, char, varchar2

How can I replace `CHAR` with `VARCHAR2` in all tables in a schema?

Note: I'm content with a query that returns the `ALTER TABLE` statements so I can save the script and run it again.

Comment: One thing to be aware of; you may have trailing spaces in your new `VARCHAR2` columns, and Oracle does consider trailing spaces to be significant in `VARCHAR2` columns, so the values `'A'` and `'A '` are not equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select 'ALTER TABLE "' || owner || '"."' || table_name
|| '" MODIFY ("' || column_name
|| '" VARCHAR2(' || data_length || '));'
from all_tab_columns tc
where data_type = 'CHAR'
and owner = :schemaname
and exists (
    select 1
    from all_tables t
    where tc.owner = t.owner
    and tc.table_name = t.table_name
);
```

Comment: I've extended the original answer to omit tables which are in the recycle bin. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446053/what-are-the-bin-tables-in-oracles-all-tab-columns-table