# What are the BIN$... tables in Oracle's ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table?

Tags: oracle

When I query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` in Oracle, I see tables called

```
BIN$frKctA83wMPgQEOSh0Az+A==$0
BIN$frKctA8cwMPgQEOSh0Az+A==$0
BIN$frQ1pdU2TgXgQEOSh0APxA==$0
BIN$frQ1pdVGTgXgQEOSh0APxA==$0
```

There is no corresponding entry in `ALL_TABLES`. What are those?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since version 10g, dropped tables (also dropped objects in general) are put in the recycle bin and can be restored easily. The names you see are tables in the recycle bin.

You can bypass the recycle bin by adding the [PURGE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9003.htm#sthref8763) keyword in your DROP statements.

You will find additional information in the [Administrator's Guide Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01511).

Comment: Do you maybe also happen to know the meaning of "DR$" tables?

Comment: @rustyx They are mentioned in the [Oracle Text documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/text.112/e16594/aoptim.htm#sthref666): *All queries look at the index token table. Its name has the form `DR$indexname$I`*

Comment: Also, "ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF" would prevent you from generating objects than can potentially fill up your tablespaces.